# Use BreezeJS and JayData Without OData

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze, single-page-application, jaydata

Can we use BreezeJS or JayData, with all of their features without OData (i.e using only ASP.NET Web API but without OData)?

Answer (score 1):

Breeze already supports this as it's default.  Breeze, by default, uses an OData format over the wire for query purposes, but this does NOT require that the server be implemented as an OData service. The standard Breeze WebApi server controller can understand this format without you having to implement an OData service. ( the same is true of our Mongo and Ruby server examples).

In fact, most of the Breeze examples show Breeze communicating directly with ASP.NET Web Api without using any of the WebApi OData implementation.

Comment: thanks, that is possible to use JayData without OData?

Comment: Yes, you can use JayData with webapi without OData, you can find a tutorial here - http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-use-jaydata-with-asp.net-web-api---i